# Crystal reports file size

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I am using crystal reports 2008,

I have an issue when adding an image into the file the file size increase over 7mb.

The original report is only around 30kb and the image is just under 300kb

Why is the report increasing to such a large file and how can I reduce this?

Answer (score 2):

Crystal doesn't always play well some image formats. I'd recommend converting the image to a 256-bit .bmp and trying it again. This will also fix any image artifacts that you'd otherwise get while printing or exporting the report.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's quite an old topic, but maybe still alive for other users.
You should open your Crystal, go into File -> Report Options and unselect the "**Retain Original Image Color Depth**" (or something similar in other CR versions).
This will reduce the final quality of the images, but drastically reduce the size of the PDF as well.
In my case, 2 dynamically added pics of ~500Kb were making an output PDF of 22MB (!!). After unflagging that, it was just a 1.2MB. Yes, the quality of the picture is worse, but in my case it was good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Another trick is to avoid resizing the image inside Crystal Designer. 
Instead, resize the image outside Crystal.